# "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property / create&update

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I try to add a Person instance with some features into the database in my project.I use mysql and jpa annotation.I have automatically created mysql table with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>create<` in `MySQLWorkBench`.Now, I want to add new entities with an "Add Person" button and list them on JSF view page. However, it doesn't add new instances to database.I assumed, I should have changed `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>create<` to `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>update<` or `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>create-update<` .

However, both of them didn't work and add new entities to the database.

applicationContext.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="secret_root_password" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.springhibernatejsf.model.Person</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="personDAO"
        class="com.springhibernatejsf.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="personService"
        class="com.springhibernatejsf.service.PersonServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springhibernatejsf" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

How should I modify hibernate properties to be able to add new entities?

EDIT:

PersonDAOImpl.java:

```
package com.springhibernatejsf.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.springhibernatejsf.model.Person;

@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonDAOImpl.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }
    @Override
    public void addPerson(Person p){
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(p);
        session.flush();
        logger.info("Person saved successfully, Person Details="+p);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Person> listPersons() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Person> personsList = session.createQuery("from Person").list();
        for(Person p : personsList){
            logger.info("Person List::"+p);
        }
        return personsList;
    }
}
```

After i click on "Add Person" button, i have the following in the logs:

```
    21:47:34.021 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
21:47:34.021 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
21:47:34.021 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - begin
21:47:34.021 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - initial autocommit status: true
21:47:34.021 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - disabling autocommit
21:47:34.022 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select person0_.id as id1_0_, person0_.country as country2_0_, person0_.name as name3_0_ from PERSON person0_
Hibernate: select person0_.id as id1_0_, person0_.country as country2_0_, person0_.name as name3_0_ from PERSON person0_
21:47:34.023 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - committing
21:47:34.023 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - committed JDBC Connection
21:47:34.023 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
21:47:34.023 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection
21:47:34.023 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
21:47:34.033 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
21:47:34.034 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
21:47:34.034 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - begin
21:47:34.034 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - initial autocommit status: true
21:47:34.034 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - disabling autocommit
21:47:34.034 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - committing
21:47:34.034 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - committed JDBC Connection
21:47:34.034 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
21:47:34.034 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection
21:47:34.035 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
21:47:34.037 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
21:47:34.037 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
21:47:34.037 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - begin
21:47:34.037 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - initial autocommit status: true
21:47:34.037 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - disabling autocommit
21:47:34.038 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select person0_.id as id1_0_, person0_.country as country2_0_, person0_.name as name3_0_ from PERSON person0_
Hibernate: select person0_.id as id1_0_, person0_.country as country2_0_, person0_.name as name3_0_ from PERSON person0_
21:47:34.039 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - committing
21:47:34.039 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - committed JDBC Connection
21:47:34.039 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
21:47:34.039 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Releasing JDBC connection
21:47:34.039 [http-bio-8085-exec-4] DEBUG o.h.e.j.i.LogicalConnectionImpl - Released JDBC connection
```

Comment: `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is used for DDL (create | alter | add table) and not for persistence operations

Comment: Please post your dao class code

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI if you put `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` as `create` it will create a new schema every time you restart your server so your old table data will be deleted. You prefer to keep `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` as `update.`

Besides if you are not able to persist the Person object in your database generally is the problem with the flush mode. Until & unless your session gets flushed the data is not persisted in the db. Check the flush mode, it should not be `NEVER`.

Comment: i understand the difference between create and update, thanks for explaining. yes, i cannot persist the person instance into the database.in dao class, session gets flushed in only addPerson().i added dao class, can you please check it if there is something missing?

Comment: logger.info("Person saved successfully, Person Details="+p); Is the value of p populating fine in the logs?

Comment: no, that's the problem, i don't see this logger.info value in the logs. i added what is seen in the logs after i click on "Add Person" button.

Comment: check the browser console when you click the add person button, check the data being sent to the server if that contains the person values. Also put a debugger where your server side code is reading the person object in the controller. Putting a debugger will help you find your missing Person :)

Comment: is it weird to see a blank browser console after clicking on add person button? :)

Comment: check your request object

Comment: i am sorry to be so disciple but i don't know how to check it.i googled it but didn't get what really means.can you tell me how to check it?

Comment: First thing learn to use firebug or any other browser tool, which would provide info about the request data you are sending to the server & what response you are getting from the server. Second put a debugger where you are reading the person object at the first place in your server side code. You will get to know that you are getting the value from the browser or not. We are unsure yet it it is a client side issue or server side.